# Validation on Account

Tags: apex, validation

I have a validation rule which fires when Account Rating is not equalled Parent Account Rating (lookup in account). I've tried below validation but it didn't work. Can someone help me with this...

```
AND(
P_A_R_E_N_T_RELATIONSHIP__c = 'TRUE' ,

AND(
NOT(TEXT(Rating) == TEXT(P_A_R_E_N_T_RELATIONSHIP__r.Rating))

))
```

Comment: when will P_A_R_E_N_T_RELATIONSHIP__c = 'TRUE'?

Comment: When I select an account in that lookup then only the validation should fire. So, I made it TRUE.

Comment: are you not using the OOTB `Account.Parent` relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first condition makes no sense, it will literally never equal true. Instead, check it is not blank:

```
AND(
  NOT(
    ISBLANK(P_A_R_E_N_T_RELATIONSHIP__c)
  ), 
  TEXT(Rating) != TEXT(P_A_R_E_N_T_RELATIONSHIP__r.Rating)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked...